# Find Nonlinear function from ordered pairs

Tags: relations, correlation

Given a set of ordered pairs, it is possible to deduce the formula that describes it, if the function (that describes it) is nonlinear?

For example, if I give you the ordered pairs:
$$
(1, 0.0998334166)\\
(3, 0.2955202067)\\
(6, 0.5646424734)\\
$$
Could you tell that $\, sin(.1x)\,$ perfectly describes this list of ordered pairs?

How can I find the equation that describes a list of ordered pairs? (assuming the list of ordered pairs is indeed described by a function, and not just an arbitrary list).

Thanks for your input.

Comment: You are meaning fitting a function to the data. What about a polynomial of order $n-1$ crossing all your $n$ points?. Or any other series, actually?

Comment: { (1,1), (1,2), (2,1) } for example?

Answer (score 0):

No matter how many points you have, there exists a polynomial that goes through all of them (assuming the $x$ coordinate is unique for each point). The process of finding this polynomial is called [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation).

There are other interpolation methods as well, but each of them target some specific output form (such as a sum of sines, piecewise linear functions, etc).

There is no general way of finding a 'simple' function for some definition of simple that fits your points well, such as $\sin(0.1x)$. For each such simple form that you are interested in you can attempt to fit your points to see if it works though.

Comment: What about any other series?. This do not answer anything, it is just a comment.

Comment: @hyprfrcb What do you mean "any other series"?